# How to use Yandex translate api to translate database records effectively

Tags: java, android

I am making an android app which translates the data stored in database (inserted by user) to Hindi using Yandex translate API. I am using AsynkTask which fetches the data from database and then make an api call to convert it into hindi and then store the translated text into an arrayList and finally displays the list using a ListView and an adapter. 
When the internet connection connection is slow, the app always crashes. Further, api call for every record in database is not a good way. Can anyone tell me how to improve my code or approach to build my app.

The code is like this:

```
private class TranslationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        @Override
       protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {

        DiaryDbHelper mDbHelper = new    DiaryDbHelper(WelcomePageActivity.this);

        //get the database in readable mode
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        //use the query method on db object to retrieve data
        String[] projection = new String[]{DiaryEntry._ID, DiaryEntry.COLUMN_CONTENT};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DiaryEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, null);

        //create an array list of contents
        contentList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //if preffered language is Hindi
        //use yandexTranslate api
        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        //String strUserName = SP.getString("username", "NA");
        // boolean bAppUpdates = SP.getBoolean("applicationUpdates",false);
        String lang_preffered = SP.getString("lang_preffered", "1");
        if (lang_preffered.equals("2")) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String translatedData = QueryUtils.fetchTranslatedData(urls[0] + "&lang=hi" + "&text=" + cursor.getString(1));
                //  contentList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                contentList.add(translatedData);
                Log.d("welcome", "displayDatabase: " + contentList.get(0));
            }
            cursor.close();
            return contentList;
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                //String translatedData = QueryUtils.fetchTranslatedData(urls[0]+cursor.getString(1));
                contentList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                // contentList.add(translatedData);
                Log.d("welcome", "displayDatabase: " + contentList.get(0));
            }
            cursor.close();
            return contentList;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> translations) {
        //super.onPostExecute(earthquakes);
        UpdateUI(translations);
    }

    public void UpdateUI(ArrayList<String> translatedList) {

        // EarthQuakeAdapter itemsAdapter = new EarthQuakeAdapter(EarthquakeActivity.this,earthquakeList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(WelcomePageActivity.this, R.layout.list_view, translatedList);
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listview.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    }
}
```